# EF Core - RowVersion with EF Core - InvalidCastException

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I have added to my Entity an RowVersion in Code

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

and applied to to my Table. In the table it is a "Raw" Type.

My problem is now, that when I call the Entity `await context.Orders....` , the System will throw an Error:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.
```

There is no mention of the Column that makes problems, but since I have no other byte[] and this is the only change I made, I guess that the Version is the problem.

I have now checked and apparently there is no RowVersion for Oralce?  What should I do here? Is there something that can mimic this or  should I just add an Date Row and always update it?

Comment: Looks to me like the `Version` property should be nullable. (i.e. `byte[]?`)

Comment: Thanks, strange that even this is checked. I have now changed the Column to "not null". Question: Is there anything else I have to do? When I create a new Order it does not work because RowVersion is null. Any idea to make it automatic in Oracle like in all the Examples?